# Returning a Symbol in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

The following example contains a function `factory` that returns a Symbol of type `Bob`. However, TypeScript seems to immediately forget the type of the return value and prevents me from assigning the return value to variable `test` one line later.

```
const bob: unique symbol = Symbol('bob')
type Bob = typeof bob

const factory = (): Bob => bob
const instance = factory()
const test: Bob = instance // Type 'symbol' is not assignable to type 'unique symbol'.
```

Iam aware an explicit type signature would solve this error:

```
const instance: typeof bob = factory();
```

or

```
const intance: Bob = factory();
```

Is there a way to fix this without modifying the variable `instance` to have an explicit type signature.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it is still impossible. Return value from function without explicit type declarations drops `unique` modifier from `symbol` type.

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37469

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24506

Answer (score 1):

`unique symbol` is produced **only** from calling `Symbol()` or `Symbol.for()`, or from **explicit** type annotations.

That's why `const instance = factory();` results in `symbol`

[Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#unique-symbol)